# loop inside replace command

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, stata

I need to build some conditional variables in my dataset.

I am doing it like this:

```
gen varx=0

replace varx=1 if resp_127=="A" | resp_128=="A"|resp_129=="A" |///
 resp_130=="A" | resp_131=="A" | resp_132=="A" ...
```

I would like to know if there is some way to put a loop in the condition, so I won't need to write `resp_127` to `resp_`n again and again. I just want to write the loop that makes conditions from `resp_127` to `resp_140` automatically.

Comment: Note that you have that many response variables all of the same kind, it's possible that a `reshape long` would be a good idea.

Comment: I agree with Nick on this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you want.

```
generate varx = 0
forvalues num = 127/140 {
    replace varx=1 if resp_`num'=="A"
    }
```

Comment: The example specified 14 variables and William's code is very good for that kind of number, and especially for more. For just a few variables, note the alternative `gen varx = inlist("A", resp_127, resp_128, resp_129)`.

Comment: I started with that technique and realized just in time that `inlist` is limited to 10 character variables. However, `inlist` can take up to 255 numeric variables, and this works well when the variable names aren't as systematic as those in this example.